# Angular 8 click is working as javascript onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

My angular app is loading in an iframe portlet.

In the parent  JSP page, I have a form and submit the invisible button, which will open a popup window from an external app.

I am trying to click that button from the angular component.

Click is not working as expected, It's working like onload. When the page is getting loaded popup is coming automatically.

Html page.

```
<html>
...
...
<!-- Left nav Menu-->
<div>
<ul>    <li>....</li>
...
<li>
   <a herf="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateToParentJspMethod('true')">Contact Us</a>
</li>
 ...
</html>
```

Component ts file

```
navigateToParentJspMethod(popupFlg: string){
console.log(popupFlg+' Test');
if(popupFlg==='true'){
    $("#parentPageFrmSubmit", window.parent.document).click();

}
```

parent Jsp page

```
<script>
function openContactUsPopUpFromExternalApp(){
.....
document.getElementById("parentPageFrm").submit();
}
</script>
<form name="parentPageFrm" id="parentPageFrm" action="parentPageFrmSubmitAction" method="post" target="openContactUsWin">
<input type="hidden".....>
......
<button type="submit" id="parentPageFrmSubmit" style="display:none" onclick="openContactUsPopUpFromExternalApp()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: try removeing `herf="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: @Doflamingo19 I agree, This is the wrong design, We are trying to incorporate new application in the existing portlet application.

Comment: @Sarma you cannot only copy the code with jquery and paste it in html page. you need to modify it to work with angular. I read your code and it cannot work now.

Comment: I suggest you to start with simple angular example because it is not the same about jquery. Angular is a frameweor, jquery is library it totally different

Comment: @Doflamingo19, How to call parent jsp function? from the angular application?

Comment: @Edison removed herf and javascript, it's not working.

Comment: @Sarma jsp doesn't exist in angular!

Comment: @Doflamingo19 Jsp doesn't exist in angular. Angular can exist in Jsp. :) My application is 10 years old. The client wants to incorporate new functionality in an existing application with new angular and Springboot, We don't have an option, Just need to find an option.

Comment: @Sarma i know i have just worked with old application. You must take the html code from jsp, paste in your html angular  page and transofrm to work with angular

Comment: @sarma sorry i don't understand, your client want new function in old application that  works in jsp and want this function in angular? so the application is a mixed old jsp whit angular?

Comment: @Doflamingo19 Yes he wants to incorporate new functionality with new features in old applications. I am trying in a different way to create js method in the parent jsp file and trying to send postmessage from angular to parent jsp and try to hit that js method. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @Doflamingo19 I am able to find a workaround and fixed this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to fix this issue.

I removed Jquery and, I did use parent.postmessage from angular to parent jsp and open popup window from my parent jsp.

Html page.

```
<html>
...
...
<!-- Left nav Menu-->
<div>
<ul>    <li>....</li>
...
<li>
   <a herf="#" (click)="navigateToParentJspMethod('true')">Contact Us</a>
</li>
 ...
</html>
```

Component ts file

```
navigateToParentJspMethod(popupFlg: string){
   console.log(popupFlg+' Test');
   var data="functionality=contactUsPopUp";
   parent.postMessage(data,*);
}
```

Parent Jsp.

```
window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);

function handleMessage(e){
  var formData= e.data;
  var formValue= formData.split(";");
  var functionality=((formValue[0].substr((formValue[0].indexOf("="))).slice(1);
  if(functionality=="contactUsPopUp"){
     document.getElementById("popupInvisibleButton").click();
  }
}
```

It did work for me. :)